# When a definite integral represents a volume?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Can we say that for a positive continuous function, each definite integral can indeed be thought of as the volume of a solid? That solid could be any 3D shape the only condition it has to meet is the cross sectional area of is equal to value of the function at that point.
I was given in my textbook the following question: The base of a solid is a circle with radius 3 find the volume of the solid if parallel cross-sections perpendicular to the base are isosceles right triangles.
Now the correct answer is to note that the area of such triangle is $a=\frac{1}{2}i^2$ where $i=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}h^2}$ and h is the hypotenuse of the triangle which we can find by placing the center of circular base of the solid at the origin and using the equation $x^2+y^2=3^2=9$ which gives us $y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and $h=2y$ finally to find the volume we integrate the expression for area $$\int_{-3}^{3}{\frac{1}{2}i^2}dx = \int_{-3}^{3}{\frac{1}{2}{\frac{1}{2}h^2}}dx = \int_{-3}^{3}{\frac{1}{2}{\frac{1}{2}4y^2}}dx = \int_{-3}^{3}{9-x^2}dx $$ which equals 36

The problem however arises when i use the angle $\theta$ to calculate the volume, here is my calculation:
If we again place the circular base at origin and then rotate the radius of the circle from 0 to $\pi$ then $y=3\sin{\theta}$ again the hypotenuse of the right isoceles triangle is $h=2y=6\sin{\theta}$ and the length of each of the other two sides of the triangle is $i^2=\frac{1}{2}h^2$ and the area of that cross section is $a=\frac{1}{2}i^2$ if i we integrate this area on the interval 0 to $\pi$ (this covers every cross section of the solid exactly once) we get
$$\int_0^{\pi}{9\sin^2{\theta}}d\theta$$
However the value this definite integral gives me is $\frac{9\pi}{2}$ which is different from what i get from the correct answer!! Isnt the volume of a solid just the integral of it's cross sectional area?

the error is that the two definite integrals do not return the same value even though they both are integrals of functions that represent the cross sectional area of the same solid!! And the limits of each integral are the interval over which the function would  span the entire length of the solid?

Comment: I mean a definite integral is just some real number, so just take a cube with side length the cube root of the integral. But this is probably not what you're looking for, so could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Lorago thank you for replying, i added more details to the question so you can understand what i mean.

Comment: The answer to your last question (which does not have a question mark) is "yes". You can always integrate the cross sectional areas to get the volume. I haven't read your question to find your error (if any).

Comment: Ethan Bolker the error is that the two definite integrals do not return the same value even though they both are integrals of functions that represent the cross sectional area of the same solid!! And the limits of each integral are the interval over which the function would  span the entire length of the solid?

Comment: Ethan Bolker try to read the question now.

Comment: Triple integrals are used to find mass by integrating density over a volume. You can do something similar to find charge in an object, it's moment of inertia, etc. Divide the value by the volume of integration and you get an average value of the density function through the volume.

Comment: TurlocTheRed thank you for replying, i am concerned only about finding the volume and what i couldn't understand was why when i represent the same solid with another function of another variable that clearly describes all the cross section of the volume in the specified interval then i get a different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that the thickness of each triangle is not just $d\theta$. For the same $d\theta$, triangles near the endpoints are thinner than triangles near the endpoints. You can work out that the correct thickness is $3\sin\theta d\theta$. Include this and you get
$$
\int_0^\pi 27\sin^3\theta d\theta = 27\cdot\frac{4}{3} = 36
$$
as expected.

Comment: If you can please elaborate more, are you saying that when swich from the integral form to the sum notation then the width of the sub interval is not the same in both cases ?